# How to run Alexa skill with the alexa-sdk on own server with Node.js without Lambda drop-in?

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit

The Alexa skill docs will eventually allow you to send webhooks to `https` endpoints. However the SDK only documents lambda style `alexa-sdk` usage. How would one go about running Alexa applications on one's own server without anything abstracting Lambda? Is it possible to wrap the `event` and `context` objects?

Answer (score 1):

You can already use your own endpoint. When you create a new skill, in the configuration tab, just choose HTTPS and provide your https endpoint. ASK will call your endpoint where you can run anything you want (tip, check ngrok.com to tunnel to your own dev machine). Regarding the `event` and `context` objects; your endpoint will receive the `event` object information. You don't need the `context` object for anything, that just lets you interact with Lambda-specific stuff (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-context-object.html). Just make sure that you comply with the (undocumented) timeouts by ASK and you are good to go.

Comment: This would meet my expectations and is what I did. However, the body object will make the the alexa sdk fail eventually. Which part of the object does it need to be passed?

Comment: Which SDK are you using? What do you mean that the body object makes it fail?

Comment: alexa-sdk for node.js where you have to `var alexa = Alexa.handler(event, context, callback);`. But the JSON body I get from Alexa is not interchangeable with the event object of Lambda in the aboce example.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do this that requires only a small change to your Skill code:

1. In your main index.js entry point, instead of:

   ```
   exports.handler = function (event, context) {
   ```

   use something like:

   ```
   exports.myAppName = function (funcEvent, res) {
   ```
2. Below that, add the following workaround:

   ```
   var event = funcEvent.body

   // since not using Lambda, create dummy context with fail and succeed functions
   const context = {
     fail: () => {
       res.sendStatus(500);
     },
     succeed: data => {
       res.send(data);
     }
   };
   ```
3. Install and use [Google Cloud Functions Local Emulator](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/emulator) on your laptop. When you start and deploy your function to the emulator, you will get back a Resource URL something like http://localhost:8010/my-project-id/us-central1/myAppName.
4. Create a tunnel with [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/). Then take the ngrok endpoint and put it in place of localhost:8010 in the Resource URL above. Your resulting fulfillment URL will be something like: https://b0xyz04e.ngrok.io/my-project-id/us-central1/myAppName
5. Use the fulfillment URL (like above) under Configuration in the Alexa dev console, selecting https as the Service Endpoint Type.